# Ingress with mirror-target, do mirrors have same request rate as to main ingress?

Tags: kubernetes

Recently been playing around with mirrors to same the same traffic to a couple of deployments.

I was wondering, while doing some load tests, are the mirror requests sent at the same rate as to the main ingress? Is the service B seeing 10k req/s or is it seeing a lower rate?

With this I mean, is possible to point traffic from a single ingress to other endpoints and check 1:1 that the performance in A is better than in B?